# Linear integro differential operator

Tags: integration, integro-differential-equations

I have stated reading Linear integral equation.\

It is mention that for a function $u:\mathbb{R}^{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$ consider the linear integrodifferential operator defined as follows:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
Lu(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}[u(x+y)-u(x)-(\nabla(u(x))y)\chi_{B_{1}}]K(y)dy,
\end{equation}

where $k:\mathbb{R}^{N}\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ is a measurable and symmetric kernel.\
It is mentioned that with the symmetry of $k,$ $L$ can be written as follows:
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
Lu(x)=p.v.\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}[u(x+y)-u(x)]k(y)dy
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}[u(x+y)+u(x-y)-2u(x)]K(y)dy.
\end{equation}
**Question:** In passing from equation (1) to (2) how does the principle value (p.v. )comes into the picture.

Comment: In fact those definitions with and without pv are made so that they make sense at least for smooth functions of compact supports. In some situations it is possible to find a a smooth function with compact support such that (2) does not exist off the pv but exists with pv. Note that for symmetric Levy kernels (1) and (3) always exist for smooth functions with compact support.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity assume that $u\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$.

Such operators arise for example in the theory of Lévy processes. This is the Lévy--Khintchine representation of the generator of a process with jump intensity given by (the Lévy measure) $K(y) dy$.

A prominent example, which I will focus on, is the fractional Laplacian, with $K(y) = |y|^{-N-\alpha}$, where $\alpha \in (0,2)$. In particular, operators with $\alpha \geq 1$ are considered.

Note that the expressions with $u$ in (1) and (3) are dominated by $\min \{1,|y|^2\}$  (Taylor expansion) and so they integrate $K$ (by the definition, the Lévy measure integrates $\min \{1,|y|^2\}$).

In (2) however, the integrand behaves only like $|y|$ for small $|y|$ and it may happen that the integral over $\mathbb{R}^N$ does not converge (for example, when $\alpha \geq 1$).

To pass from (1) to (2), you first represent the integral as the limit of integrals over $B(0,\epsilon)^c$ with $\epsilon \to 0$. You split as follows:
$$\int_{B(0,\epsilon)^c} (u(x+y) - u(x) - y\nabla u(x)\chi_{B_1}(y)) K(y) dy = \int_{B(0,\epsilon)^c} (u(x+y) - u(x)) K(y) dy - \int_{B(0,\epsilon)^c}y\nabla u(x) K(y) \chi_{B_1}(y)dy.$$
The last integral is equal to zero by the symmetry of $K$. By passing to the limit you get that (1) = (2), but on the right hand side you have to write $p.v.$ because in general the integral over $\mathbb{R}^N$ does not exist.